# RTTI check fails on remote Linux machine

Tags: c++, linux, qt, xming

I use C++/Qt for my project and I am facing this strange issue.

My application runs fine on any native Linux machine and Windows. The problem appears when I use a remote Linux machine to execute my program and use a X Windows server (I use Xming) to view/use it.The debugger points to a line where the dynamic_cast fails to get the object pointer(the cast returns a nice NULL) instead of the actual object I wanted.

I suspect some configuration issue which I must be missing to enable these runtime checks.

Anyone has faced such issues, any pointers towards a solution would be welcome.

Comment: Sample code will be helpful.

Comment: Note: Is valid for `dynamic_cast<>` to return NULL. This happens when casting a pointer to an unrelated pointer type.

Comment: But this is unlikely to be anything to do with X. RTTI is by default on on modern systems so to rule out this posability we need to know the OS (and version) of your remote system and the the comiler (and version) used to build the application.

Comment: @LokiAstari But if you've encountered exactly the same problem, you can make a guess:-).  (And it took us a couple of days to figure out why `dynamic_cast` was returning a null pointer when it shouldn't, and even then, it was only a guess.  But when we fixed things up to avoid the issue, it worked, so I guess the guess was right.)

Comment: @LokiAstari Remote machine : gcc version 4.3.2 20081105 ( Red Hat 4.3.2-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After a lot of trials this was the solution.

I needed to export the interface classes explicitly, using 
**attribute**((visibility("default")))
And to make sure there is an entry in the vtable, define and empty virtual destructor for this.

It seems on some linux machines, if I don't export It does not recognize the RTTI, and returns a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

How have you linked?  We had a similar problem with our Java
plug-ins.  If the `dynamic_cast` is in a different DLL than the
DLL where the object was constructed, `RTLD_GLOBAL` must be set
in the call to `dlopen` when the DLLs are loaded.  If the DLLs
are loaded implicitly, whether it is set will depend on how  it
was set for the DLL triggering the load (which means that you
may have no control over it).  In the end, we had to ensure that
*no* `.so` were loaded implicitly (by having Java load a special
loader DLL, which loaded everything explicitly, in the
dependency order).

Note that this may not be your problem; I'm just guessing, since
I don't have enough information.  But we had exactly the same
symptoms.

Comment: You mean I am loading the dll differently in the remote machine than in the local ones. I need to do some checks to find if that is the case.

Comment: That's what it sounds like.